# How to execute a bash script through a CGI script written in Python?

Tags: python, cgi

I am trying to use a **CGI script written in Python** to **execute a bash script**, however it only works correctly when I run the script python manually. When I run via Browser, the CGI execution returns 200, however the bash script does not run.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do, but using two simple scripts just to explain, okay?

The cgi script was created in the following apache directory and is accessible without problems:
**/var/www/cgi-bin/raf_teste.cgi**

Below is the content of the **raf_teste.cgi** script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import subprocess
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
command = ['./raf.sh']
subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Within the same directory **"/var/www/cgi-bin/"** a BashScript named **raf.sh** was created:
**/var/www/cgi-bin/raf.sh**

Below is the content of the raf.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "rafael" > "/tmp/rafael.txt"
```

**Note:** In the test I did using the python subprocess module to run linux command, everything worked perfectly, but in this case I am trying to run another script through a python CGI, it is not working and no error message is displayed.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Are you sure the web server doesn't have its own private `/tmp`?

Comment: Is `raf.sh` executable by the user that the web server is running as?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams 
I have already tried other directories with 777 permissions and even then it can not write and it also does not give me an error message. I've been testing for days.

Comment: @rbricheno
I set the 777 permission on the raf.sh script

Answer (score 1):

Okay, pretty sure I've got it.

The problem is that you ran your script by hand before you ran it on the web.

That caused `"/tmp/rafael.txt"` to be created, owned by your user. Now, no other user (including the web server user) can write to that file because the file already exists, owned by you, and [that's how /tmp works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71625).

The solution is easy: delete `"/tmp/rafael.txt"`. Then I bet your script works.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help. I tried to remove the file and tried to change the destination directory, but the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry this didn't work, I have a test environment set up and this worked for me. What web server are you using, and can you read the error log of the web server? For apache it would be something like /var/log/apache2/error.log